# Wanted: TofC field command to mix Caption labels in one table

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, caption

My exact config at the moment:  I created an "Appendix" style, then created a Caption label "Appendix-B-" to distinguish figure numbering in the appendix from figure numbering in the main body of the document.  (I'm aware of the bass-ackwards tricks like redefining "Heading9" to look like an appendix, but prefer not to go that route).  what I'd like is to be able to have a single TofC which shows all "Figure" and "Appendix B-" caption labels in one table.  My current approach is to have two tables in sequence,

```
TOC \h \z \c "Figure" 
TOC \h \z \c "Appendix B -"
```

Is there any way to merge those fields into one?  I could see additional applications of such a capability, e.g. a TofC for two or more intermingled Caption labels in the body of a document.

Comment: And believe me, if I could convert to LaTex w/in my corporate environment, I would :-(

Comment: just a shot in the dark but have you tried adding more than one identifier by using commas, kind of like what can be done with the style switch? Just a thought.

Comment: @Adam - I've tried a variety of "conjoiners" but the `TOC` field appears to ignore all but the first or last "\c 'something'" argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best -- or maybe only -- non-macro  solution is provided at this blog:

http://insight.trueinsight.za.com/archives/276  and http://insight.trueinsight.za.com/archives/426

in brief, he recommends using `StyleRef` fields to specify what style (`Heading X` vs. `Appendix`, in my case) to use when applying table or figure captions. Unfortunately, that fails when both "Figures" and "Tables" are in the appendix.  His final conclusion is to do what I did in the first place.